# What is the correct term for this type of USB Input devices?

Tags: usb, switches, input, gpio

[image: a button]

Hi, I'm working on something where I need to use a huge amout of these little guys (picture attached), probably around 32 or more for a start.. The problem is, I need to be able to connect all of them to my computer using 1 single USB (or COM port). To do so I need a device or a controller that have alot of inputs bi-pin attached to it, but I just can't figure out the name or the correct term to search for it on ebay. I'm starting to think it doesn't even exist..

All I keep getting when searching for this, is some USB AUDIO/MP3 input stuff that has nothing to do with what I need. Please help with anything you have. Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking about the switch itself (limit switch) or about some USB device that can accept 32 digital inputs?

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I am talking about the USB device, sorry if my post wans't clear

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Assumption**: *The question is about a device to transmit 32 or more digital inputs to a PC over USB.*

The device you are looking for is a 32-port (or more) **USB GPIO module**:

- Ideally with integrated pull-up or pull-down resistors, so the state of those limit switches can be directly sensed
- Ideally with a USB HID interface so a bespoke USB device driver is not required

There are several such devices commercially available, such as:

- Diolan PC-I2C/SPI/GPIO [Interface Adapter DLN-1](http://www.diolan.com/products/dln1.html) includes pull-up resistors for each channel
- Numato Lab [32 channel USB GPIO module](http://numato.com/32-channel-usb-gpio-module)
  [image: USB GPIO]

While the capabilities of these devices include both input and output, and on some channels analog input as well, the functionality in the question is a subset of these, and thus well served by these modules.

---

Alternatively, an **Arduino Mega** (or clone) provides all this functionality, 54 GPIOs, plus flexible programmability. Thus it is a superset of the GPIO modules mentioned above. They are sold on eBay and other sites for [under $15](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1PCS-ATmega2560-16AU-Board-with-USB-Cable-For-IDE-MEGA-2560-NEW-Arrival-Super-/271150447339?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3f21d37aeb).

[image: Arduino Clone Mega]

Add on a [Mega Sensor Shield](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Mega-Sensor-Shield-V2-0-V2-For-Arduino-ATMEGA-2560-R3-1280-ATmega8U2-ATMEL-AVR-/170935388900?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27cc8b0ae4), and you will have 54 GPIOs available to you as **separate 3-pin connector blocks** each with GND, VCC and IO pin, each with the facility of programmable pull-up resistors internal to the microcontroller:

[image: Mega Sensor Shield]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you very much ! It solved my problem

Comment: Just a note, the Arduino solution does require programming, possibly on both sides.

Comment: @Passerby Very true. IIRC there's a Processing sketch for the computer side, and corresponding Arduino sketch out there that does exactly what the OP desires, but that's one extra step.

Comment: Or v-usb in a usb-hid setup so it only needs programming on microcontroller side.

Answer (score 5):

Those are microswitches, or micro lever switches.

As for the usb part, I believe you mean a `usb gpio` controller/module/board. 32 channels for all 32 switches. A better option might be a diy method, using a microcontroller and some gpio expanders.

USB Arcade Interfaces would also work. Most are input only, which is all you need (unless you have a need to output from the same board). And incidentally, are designed to work with microswitches, as those are what are used for Arcade buttons.

But you might need more than one, as the arcade interfaces commonly come with only 28 inputs (2 players, 10 buttons + 4 directions each). Same goes for the USB GPIO modules, sometimes it is cheaper to get two smaller ones than one huge 32 channel one.

Comment: This is the first time I hear about "GPIO", it's probably what I was looking for! Thank you very much sir.

Comment: @Reacen GPIO is the common term for a "General Purpose Input/Output" pin. It's the main thing you need for any digital input or control from a microcontroller, or even computer, but it's just not something most consumers need :D